# Apache Spark streaming mapping object and printing attribute

Tags: scala, streaming, apache-spark

I'm reading from a text file, parsing each line to JSON and am attempting to print one of the attributes:

```
val msgData = ssc.textFileStream(dataDir)

val msgs = msgData.map(MessageParser.parse)
msgs.foreach(msg => println(msg.my_attribute))
```

However, I get the following error on compilation:

```
value my_attribute is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[com.imgzine.analytics.messages.Message]
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: What is the signature of `MessageParser.parse`?

Comment: @om-nom-nom This: def parse(msg: String): Message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark Streaming discretizes a stream of data by creating micro-batch containers. Those are called 'DStreams'  and contain a collection of RDD's.

Translated to your case, you need to operate on the content of the RDD, not the DStream:

```
msgs.foreach(rdd => rdd.foreach(elem => println(elem.my_attribute))
```

DStreams offer a help method to print the first elements (10 I think) of each RDD:

`dstream.print()`

Of course, that will just invoke .toString on the objects contained in the RDD and print the result. Maybe not what you want with `my_attribute` as stated in the question.

Comment: I confirm that it prints the first 10 (if there are >= 10 elements in the RDD).